# Android temporary files

Tags: android

please give me list of android temporary files or give me list of temporary file extension in android....

Comment: Please give it a try and formulate a more specific question, otherwise you will get no specific answer! Follow the guidelines!

Comment: Also, focus on what you are trying to achieve. It sounds like you want to be able to free up space without removing permanent files -- is that it?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as "temporary files" in Android.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean temporary files created while coding Android apps, here's the [.gitignore](https://github.com/scottwd9/beginning-android-2/blob/master/.gitignore) I use. It includes android, eclipse, windows, linux, and mac. The android specific ones are the chunk at the top:

```
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated GUI files
*R.java
```